# How can I set a local branch to pull / merge from a particular remote branch?

Tags: git

I have a local branch foo that started life as a branch off of master. Then I pushed it to my remote, and it's now happily living life with its siblings in remotes/origin

I want pull to automatically pull from remotes/origin/foo, and I want status -sb to show me how many changes I am ahead of remotes/origin/foo.

I thought the way to do this was

```
git config branch.foo.merge 'refs/heads/foo'
```

However, after doing that, I get this message:

```
➔ git status -sb
## foo
➔ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'foo'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `branch.foo.remote` set correctly?

Comment: No, it was not. That fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that both `branch.foo.remote` and `branch.foo.merge` are set correctly before `git pull` without parameters will work correctly.

Note that you can also use `-u` or `--set-upstream` with `git push` to set this information on a push operation.